# Why do I get an error in laravel 8 log but not in browser

Tags: laravel, include

I normally duplicate a project to start a new one.  In the browser, there is no error.  The page displays properly.  In Laravel log I get the following error, although the file fn_table.php is there.  If I remove the file, I get an error in the browser.

```
[2021-08-27 09:55:45] local.ERROR: include_once(public/fn/fn_table.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): include_once(public/fn/fn_table.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory at /Users/paul/WebSites/MeerkatSafaris/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php:12)
[stacktrace]
#0 /Users/paul/WebSites/MeerkatSafaris/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php(12): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'include_once(pu...', '/Users/paul/Web...', 12)
#1 /Users/paul/WebSites/MeerkatSafaris/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php(12): include_once()
#2 /Users/paul/WebSites/MeerkatSafaris/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(480): include('/Users/paul/Web...')
#3 /Users/paul/WebSites/MeerkatSafaris/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(346): Composer\\Autoload\\includeFile('/Users/paul/Web...')
#4 /Users/paul/WebSites/MeerkatSafaris/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(735): Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader->loadClass('App\\\\Providers\\\\A...')
#5 /Users/paul/WebSites/MeerkatSafaris/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(669): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolveProvider('App\\\\Providers\\\\A...')
#6 /Users/paul/WebSites/MeerkatSafaris/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php(75): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->register('App\\\\Providers\\\\A...')
#7 /Users/paul/WebSites/MeerkatSafaris/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(649): Illuminate\\Foundation\\ProviderRepository->load(Array)
#8 /Users/paul/WebSites/MeerkatSafaris/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/RegisterProviders.php(17): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->registerConfiguredProviders()
#9 /Users/paul/WebSites/MeerkatSafaris/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(237): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\RegisterProviders->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application))
#10 /Users/paul/WebSites/MeerkatSafaris/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(310): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#11 /Users/paul/WebSites/MeerkatSafaris/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(127): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->bootstrap()
#12 Command line code(1): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#13 {main}
```

What is happening?

In fact these errors are all over my project.

I learned how to create a file with global functions by listing their path in the autoload varibale in the composer.json.  This is ok for functions used all over the project.

However, it happens that I need some global functions only in some controllers.  I normally use php include_once which works 100% but generates the above error in the log.

What is the way around that?

And why is the laravel log reports an error on a file which is there?

Comment: did you add that 'include_once(public/fn/fn_table.php)' to AppServiceProvider?

Comment: I think your Laravel app can't even boot up.

Comment: But everything works ok in the browser.  I also look at the original project, and I have the same error in the log, but everything works fine in the browser.

Comment: I have edited my original post...

Comment: Try to write include_once with absolute path.

Comment: @FatimaMazhit How can I do that on both local and web server?

Comment: You can do with `public_path().'/fn/fn_table.php'`

Comment: @FatimaMazhit I did and it works... no more errors!  Thank you.